# Is there a way to just refresh the lightning custom tab while saving a record in the lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

```
      [![<aura:component>
        <aura:attribute name="oppRecordId" type="String" access="public"/>
        <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" access="private"/>
        <lightning:navigation aura:id="navigationApi"/>
        <lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notificationApi"/>
        <aura:attribute name="objectDetailData" access="public" type="Detail__c"/>
        <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
        <lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overLayLib"/>
        <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="neweditForm" objectApiName="Detail__c"
                                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                  onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
                                  onsubmit="{!c.submitForm}"
                                  onerror="{!c.handleError}">
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Opportunity__c" value="{!v.oppRecordId}" class="slds-hide"/>
            <div class="slds-section slds-is-open">
                    <h3 class="slds-section__title slds-theme_shade">
                        <span class="slds-truncate slds-p-horizontal_small" title="Section Title">Address</span>
                    </h3>
                    <div aria-hidden="false" class="slds-section__content"></div>
                </div>
            <lightning:layout multipleRows="true" horizontalAlign="spread" pullToBoundary="small">
                <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="horizontal-small">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Street_c" value="{!v.objectDetailData.Street_c}"/>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
            <div class="modal-footer slds-modal__footer">
                <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" type="button" variant="brand" label="cancel" onclick="{!c.cancel}"/>
                <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" type="submit" variant="brand" label="Save"/>
            </div>
            </lightning:recordEditForm> 
</aura:component>][1]][1]
```

Controller.js

```
handleSuccess : function(component, event, helper){
        component.find("overLayLib").notifyClose();
    },
    cancel: function (component, event, helper) {
        //alert('cancel')
        component.find("overLayLib").notifyClose();
    },
submitForm : function (component,event,helper) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        var eventFields = event.getParam("fields");
        var objJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(eventFields));
        component.find("neweditForm").submit(eventFields);

    },
```

Comment: you can by using `workspaceAPI`. please go through https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_refreshTab.htm

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising.. I will give it a try.